# Horizontal one-page layout how?

Tags: css

I have requirement on creating website which has all the sites in index and horizontaly beside each other.

Each of the site would be big for 100% width of the browser. So if you open webpage you can see only first page. You click on the link with #next link and it will "slide you to the left", to the next page.

I have everything ready, just cannot get how to position those sites beside each other. float doesnt work, it goes under each other.

### I hope someone can understand this hehe. Thanks for advice

I have found a solution already.

Check out (great) new function in CSS3 `calc()`

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/

Comment: Check this answer about [horizontal page sliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646) it should fullfill your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to float them all left, but remember to set 'overflow: hidden;' on your container element, this way they should stay in line.

You can then use JS in some guise to 'slide' them about.

Comment: It should work, it's how I do image sliders on a smaller scale which extend outside of their parent box on some websites. How is your HTML looking?

Comment: yeah but i dont want to slide images, I want to slide entire webpage.

Comment: Yeah, the concept is the same though, in my case, the images are purely contained inside 'divs' and that's what you'd want to slide.

Comment: You still don't get it... Anyway, I already found solution, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/create-a-horizontal-scrolling-website.html

From the sound of it, you should be able to convert what you have into what you want pretty easily, and that tutorial is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Well give us a clue, what went wrong? :P Maybe something like http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/ which is a jQuery plugin, and pretty easy to implement? Hard to suggest anything else without knowing why the first one was no good :)

Comment: its working, just not exactly what i need... I will check out completely the jquery one maybe i can edit it somehow