# Responsive horizontal page sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I want to create **horizontal responsive page navigation** as illustrated by the below image :
[image: horizontal responsive page navigation transition]

This is what I have managed to do : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/ZVgsk/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slideNum = $('.page').length,
        wrapperWidth = 100 * slideNum,
        slideWidth = 100/slideNum;
    $('.wrapper').width(wrapperWidth + '%'); 
    $('.page').width(slideWidth + '%');
    
    $('a.scrollitem').click(function(){
        $('a.scrollitem').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        
        var slideNumber = $($(this).attr('href')).index('.page'),
            margin = slideNumber * -100 + '%';
    
        $('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
nav{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    height:30px;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background: #263729;
}
.page {
    float:left;
    background: #992213;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#page-1 {
    background: #0C717A;
}
#page-2 {
    background: #009900;
}
#page-3 {
    background: #0000FF;
}
a {
    color:#FFF;
}
a.selected{
    color: red;
}


.simulate{
    height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <a href="#page-1" class="scrollitem selected">page 1</a>
         <a href="#page-2" class="scrollitem">page 2</a>
         <a href="#page-3" class="scrollitem">page 3</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="page-1" class="page"> 
         <h3>page 1</h3>
        <div class="simulate">Simulated content heigher than 100%</div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-2" class="page">  
         <h3>page 2</h3>
        <div class="simulate">Simulated content heigher than 100%</div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-3" class="page"> 
        <h3>page 3</h3>
        <div class="simulate">Simulated content heigher than 100%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have however hit a few brick walls, as mine is responsive to a certain degree, its just as you scale it needs to stick to the page its on and not reveal the others.

Also if the pages are long it shows a scroll bar which is perfect, but on the last slide there is a gap as wide as the scroll-bar.

I have the following Requirements:

1. Needs to be Responsive
2. pages need to be able to be long (800px) and still scrollable, without the gap on the last one.
3. needs to work on minimum ie9

Comment: Your jsFiddle is broken

Comment: its just the transitions that are not working, that's why you don't see the slide effect.. not sure why its broken.. Also its currently set at 960, just expand the preview window

Comment: I think you want this effect: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: updated question (this jsfiddle actually works)

Comment: Is this a browser specific thing? I just had a look and see no problems (on chrome, at least)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using all these libraries? your can achieve this layout effect only with jQuery library...

Comment: no particular reason, just the only way i could think of, but please educate me, would be wonderful to only use jquery..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Horizontal page sliding

*with left-margin animation*

This jQuery snippet :

1. Calculates the number of slides and set the width of the wrapper accordingly.
2. According to which link is clicked, `left-margin` is animated on the wrapper to show the corresponding slide with a smooth transition
3. Toggles the class of the clicked link for active link highlighting

Note that this solution:

1. Uses only one menu occurence to minimize markup and prevent content repetition.
2. Requires only the jQuery library
3. works for a **dynamic number of slides**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideNum = $('.page').length,
    wrapperWidth = 100 * slideNum,
    slideWidth = 100 / slideNum;
  $('.wrapper').width(wrapperWidth + '%');
  $('.page').width(slideWidth + '%');

  $('a.scrollitem').click(function() {
    $('a.scrollitem').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var slideNumber = $($(this).attr('href')).index('.page'),
      margin = slideNumber * -100 + '%';

    $('.wrapper').animate({
      marginLeft: margin
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background: #263729;
}

.page {
  float: left;
  background: #992213;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#page-1 {
  background: #0C717A;
}

#page-2 {
  background: #009900;
}

#page-3 {
  background: #0000FF;
}

a {
  color: #FFF;
}

a.selected {
  color: red;
}

.simulate {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="#page-1" class="scrollitem selected">page 1</a>
    <a href="#page-2" class="scrollitem">page 2</a>
    <a href="#page-3" class="scrollitem">page 3</a>
  </nav>
  <div id="page-1" class="page">
    <h3>page 1</h3>
    <div class="simulate">Simulated content heigher than 100%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-2" class="page">
    <h3>page 2</h3>
    <div class="simulate">Simulated content heigher than 100%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-3" class="page">
    <h3>page 3</h3>
    <div class="simulate">Simulated content heigher than 100%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a much better approach.  Scrolling is hacky

Comment: this is a lot better thank you! Just one final question though, i see the page width and the wrapper width are dependent on how many pages there are, unfortunately the content being loaded is entirely dynamic.. any recommended work around?

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven BTW are you able to change the HTML?

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven even better, only one menu occurence : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wtvaJ/2/

Comment: Wow, thanks again for all your help, learned a lot from you... i would award you the 50pts but apparently have to wait 11hours

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven don't worry about that, you can just forget about it, as you accepted my answer, it will be awarded automaticaly when bounty ends.

Comment: Hi i have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532381/jquery-on-click-animation-only-happens-after-first-click , I just thought that your probably the best person to ask, if you have 5mins to look at it..

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven thks for the compliment :) unfortunatly I didn't have time to look at it but it looks like you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**"as you scale it needs to stick to the page its on and not reveal the others"**

To achieve this, keep a reference to the current page element and then do a no-delay scrollTo this element when the window is resized:

```
var currentPage; //here is where we will hold the reference
jQuery('a.scrollitem').click(function () {
    var targetPage = $(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
    jQuery('a.scrollitem').removeClass('selected');
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
    jQuery('.toggle').css({'display':'none'});
    jQuery('.wrapper').scrollTo(targetPage, 1200, function(){
        jQuery('.toggle').css({'display':'block'});
    });
    currentPage = targetPage; //here is where we set the reference
    return false;
});

//and here we do a no-delay scrollTo
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(!!currentPage){
        console.log('window resized.  scrolling to: ', currentPage.attr('id'));
        jQuery('.wrapper').scrollTo(currentPage);
    }
});
```

This makes it pretty responsive, in my opinion.

**pages need to be able to be long (800px) and still scrollable, without the gap on the last one.**

To get rid of that gap, I just make all `page`s a little longer than they need to be.  The scrolling is not affected by this since the pages are left-justified with `left:0;`.  I suspect that the other pages had the same gap and and that the gaps on those pages were covered by the scroll bar.

```
.page {
    width: 110%;
}
```

**needs to work on minimum ie9**

I'm afraid I can't help in this regard; I have only IE11 installed.  But hey, it works great in IE11.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/Bt8y3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works but... is there no way to fix the jerkiness when you slowly scale the window down.. also if i make it 110% width it hides content when the screen becomes smaller...

Comment: as far as the jerkiness... that's because it's constantly scrolling!  You could add a delay so that it wasn't updating so frequently but then you would see gaps.